# Bash script to convert column data into rows

Tags: bash

I have data in a comma separate file. This is the structure of the input file.

**code, day_1, day_2, day_3**

- 1235, 0,  21,     6
- 1236, 9,  3,      4
- 1237, 1,  7,      3

I would like transform it, and display the column data as row entries

**code,  day, count**

- 1235, day_1, 0
- 1235, day_2, 21
- 1235, day_3, 6
- 1236, day_1, 9
- 1236, day_2, 3
- 1236, day_3, 4
- 1237, day_1, 1
- 1237, day_2, 7
- 1237, day_3, 3

Here's my code and output.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
file='test_file.in'
IFS=$','
while read -r code day_1 day_2 day_3
do
        #echo "$code, $branch, $description"
        count=1
        while [ $count -le 3 ]
        do

                day_var=""'$day_'"${count}"
                #echo $day_var
                echo "$code, day_${count}, $day_var"
                count=$[$count+1]
        done
done < $file
```

**Output**:

120006, day_1, $day_1
120006, day_2, $day_2
120006, day_3, $day_3
120007, day_1, $day_1
120007, day_2, $day_2
120007, day_3, $day_3
140197, day_1, $day_1
140197, day_2, $day_2
140197, day_3, $day_3

Kindly suggest a bash script solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A quick awk solution:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print $1,"day_"(i-1),$i}' file
```

**Why is your code not working:**

There are many reasons why this is not the best code, but the main are in the following two lines:

```
day_var=""'$day_'"${count}"
echo "$code, day_${count}, $day_var"
```

You would like to use a variable name which you actually created from variables. This is called indirection and there is a nice [BashFAQ/006](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) about it.

When we would fix your code, it would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/evn bash
file='test_file.in'
while IFS=, read -r code day_1 day_2 day_3
do
        for (( count=1;count<=3; count++)); do
                day_var="day_${count}"
                echo "$code, day_${count}, ${!day_var}"
        done
done < $file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file='test_file.in'
while IFS=, read -r code day_1 day_2 day_3
do
        #echo "$code, $branch, $description"
        count=1
        while [ $count -le 3 ]
        do
                day_var=day_$count
                echo "$code, $day_var, ${!day_var}"
                count=$((count+1))
        done
done < "$file"
```

Compare it with yours.

But my approach would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r code day1 day2 day3; do
    printf '%s, day_1,%s\n%s, day_2,%s\n%s, day_3,%s\n' \
        "$code" "$day1" "$code" "$day2" "$code" "$day3"
done < file
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciated.